# Why did the Apollo cabin repressurization valve cause a banging sound?

Tags: apollo-program, history, sound

As portrayed in the movie *Apollo 13*, Fred Haise tried to spook his crewmates by trigerring the cabin repressurization valve, which creates a banging sound.  Indeed, every Apollo crew reported hearing this sound from that valve:

> All crews reported that reaction control firings were much more audible in the lunar module than in the command module.  Crews also reported hearing **the sharp shotgunlike report made by the closure of the cabin repressurization valve**, the glycol pump whine, the grinding of the S-band antenna, and several pyrotechnic firings.  Although sometimes annoying, these noise cues were often helpful as indications of proper system functioning.
>
> *Apollo Program Summary Report*, April 1975, p. 6-6

Why would this valve create such a sound?  Is it an example of a [water hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_hammer) effect?

Comment: Argh, I feel like I just ran across some information on this in the last week or so while looking up something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Odds are it was the spring slamming the valve closed.

Green arrows are the flow path. Red arrow shows the spring.

[image]

Diagram from [Apollo Spacecraft News Reference](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/CSM_News_Reference_H_Missions.pdf) page 122